# How to open System Data Usage Activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anybody tell me how to open Data usage from android settings from my app? I do not now which Intent I should call.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works well for using the below code in my project:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings",
                "com.android.settings.Settings$DataUsageSummaryActivity"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And you can see the package info from here:
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/cm-12.0/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

[ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html?hl=ru#ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE)

```
public static final String ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE
```

> Activity Action: Show settings for managing network data usage of a specific application. Applications should define an activity that offers options to control data usage.

Constant Value: `android.intent.action.MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE`

Also maybe [this link](http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2013/02/making-your-applications-data-usage.html) will help you.

Comment: ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE brings up a menu that lists applications with that action in their intent filters, I want to only open that activity

Comment: What applicatins are in that list?

Comment: applications that has "ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE" in their AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: Sure but are there Settings or System Data Usage?

Comment: Try to choose it. Possible you'll see activity that you need.